# 2013 - How come I do not see the suite links on my site?

Tags: publishing-site, newsfeed, suite-links

I have created a new publishing site in SharePoint Server 2013 and there are no Suite Links (Newsfeed, SkyDrive, Sites) in the Suite Links bar.  Is there some feature I need to enable to get them to show up?  I have googled the heck out of this and cannot find information about this allegedly OOB feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another forum someone has claimed I need to install a User Profile Service and even MySites in order to get this feature to appear.  I hesitate to do this at the moment but when I do I'll mark this as the answer.  Hopefully this helps someone with a similar question since apparently nobody else on StackExchange has this same issue.

*Update* - YES, installing and syncing the User Profile Service caused the Suite Links to start showing up.

Comment: I'll unmark later if it turns out not to be the answer.